# OpenStreetMaps MySQL Database. Retrieve POI and street names

Tags: mysql, geo, openstreetmap

In one of my projects I have a issue to get the nearest street name and Point of Interest to some some coordinates. I am using OSM local database. I have imported some geo area to my MySQL database.
To create it I followed this nice article http://goblor.de/wp/2009/10/16/openstreetmap-projekt-teil-1-openstreetmap-daten-in-mysql-datenbank-einlesen/
So I am using this structure http://goblor.de/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/schema1.png

And now, I have a problem. I don't know how to retrieve data from it. I have some coordinates. My goal is to get the nearest road name and POI to it.

Does anyone have some ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that tutorial is only inserting the lat/lon coordinates. You will need to create geometry types and index them in order to query them spatially.

MySQL's spatial extensions are usually not the best solution for this sort of thing. I'd recommend using PostgreSQL if at all possible.

See this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27878/how-to-find-20-closest-points-efficiently

and here for converting OSM:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I need mysql. Base is not so huge. I'm searching information , that describes key value variants in base. some examples of queries....

Comment: lemme know if you was able to go futher!!??